# sort before group in my sql

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by, group-concat

I'm trying to sort a table (comments) before it is grouped, so I created a temp table called `comm_sorted` and sorted it by timestamp.

However, its still doesn't work.

```
    $sql = "
select images.id,images.image as imageURL, images.fid as userID, user.name as userFullName, images.comment as feedDescription, images.sharedServices, stores.name as customerName, 
CONCAT('[', 
GROUP_CONCAT(
DISTINCT CONCAT('\"',likes.uid,'\"')),']') as likes , 
CONCAT('[', 
GROUP_CONCAT(
DISTINCT CONCAT('{\"userId\":\"',comm_sorted.uid,'\",\"comment\":\"',comm_sorted.comment,'\",\"timeStamp\":\"',comm_sorted.timestamp,'\"}') separator ','),']')  as comments FROM images 
LEFT JOIN stores on images.client_id=stores.id 
LEFT JOIN likes on images.id=likes.feedid 
LEFT JOIN (select * from comments order by timestamp DESC) as comm_sorted on images.id=comm_sorted.feedid  
LEFT JOIN user on images.fid=user.id WHERE images.fid=:userID group by images.id, user.name, images.image, images.comment, images.sharedServices, stores.name order by images.Timestamp 
DESC LIMIT $offset, $limit";
```

Comment: but why is it important to sort an interim dataset?  you should only worry about sorting the final results

Comment: i'm basically creating an array of objects per row in the final result. I want to sort those objects (comments). rows are list of images, and for each image i am listing all the comments for this image. I want the comments to be sorted by timestamp

Comment: it is wasteful and useless to sort any subquery or preliminary data set before aggregaton (GROUP BY).  the ORDER BY clause should ONLY be applied to the final result.  if you go to sqlfiddle.com and make your tables and put some data in, i can help you build your query

Comment: Hi foampile, first thanks! - did u understand my requirement (i added a comment above) - so its critical for me to sort the data preliminary as i'm also displaying it (each row has an array of objects from this preliminary data)

Comment: the only way i can think of is to dump the preliminary data in a temp table, display that, and then run the aggregation.  are you familiar with temp tables?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i tried to do, see the sql in the question

Comment: this is the temp one - LEFT JOIN (select * from comments order by timestamp DESC) as comm_sorted

Comment: but there is no reason to be doing sorting in a subquery the FROM/JOIN clause.  if you are displayimg the contents of the temp table before you join it in another query then yes, here you clearly have no reason

Comment: as you can see i'm displaying the content from the temp table - i am generating an array of objects from this temp table, and show it in the results (i'm showing a list of images, and for each image i'm showing all the comments that were posted on that image)

Comment: you are not displaying it when it is in a subquery you are joining to.  if you want to sort the final result, put the ORDER BY at the end.

Comment: the order by in the end is not helping as you can not sort data that is already grouped.  so how do u change my query to make it work ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sort inside array of objects that is being created in a mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635570/sort-inside-array-of-objects-that-is-being-created-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: got an answer in another thread from Mr. Barmar - You can put an ORDER BY comm_sorted.timestamp option in the GROUP_CONCAT() function.  So no need to do a temp query!  Thanks Barmar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Mr. Barmar - You can put an ORDER BY comm_sorted.timestamp option in the GROUP_CONCAT() function. No need for a temp query.  question closed.